# Calculating z values for all rows in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I used the following Query for calculating z scores in MySql.The Table gainfinal consists of three columns countrycode, year and values. I want to calculate z scores for the values.

```
SELECT (g.values - stats.average) / stats.st AS zvalue
FROM  `gainfinal` g CROSS JOIN
(select STDDEV(values) as st, AVG(values) as average) stats;
```

I ran this query but it said - #1064 error. How can I calculate z scores for all the rows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VALUES` is a keyword in MySQL. Escape it by enclosing it in backticks.

```
SELECT (g.`values` - stats.average) / stats.st AS zvalue
FROM  `gainfinal` g
CROSS JOIN
(select STDDEV(`values`) as st, AVG(`values`) as average) stats;
```

Comment: I have just tried this one. But it says- Unknown column 'values' in 'field list'.

Comment: @user3934131 You're missing the `FROM` clause in `CROSS JOIN`'s `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Did you mean I should add FROM before stats. CROSS JOIN
(select STDDEV(`values`) as st, AVG(`values`) as average) FROM stats;

Comment: @Civaist `CROSS JOIN (select STDDEV(values) as st, AVG(values) as average FROM <whichever table exists, I think gainfinal>) temp;` where, `temp` is temporary table's name/alias. It is needed by MySQL for its own purposes.